# Losing some messages when published in a rabbitmq queue

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I'm working on a project using go and rabbitmq. When I publish a large amount of messages, some messages are not published to the queue.

I am using the following code to publish messages in queue

```
func Publish(queue commonModel.Queue, content []byte) commonModel.Queue {

    error := queue.Channel.Publish(
        "",
        queue.Name,
        false, // mandatory
        false, // immediate
        amqp.Publishing{

            DeliveryMode: amqp.Persistent,
            ContentType:  "application/json",
            Body:         []byte(content),
        })

    queue.Error = error

    return queue
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why some messages are not published in the queue?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: The godocs of `github.com/streadway/amqp` say that "Since publishings are asynchronous, any undeliverable message will get returned by the server." and "Publishings can be undeliverable when the mandatory flag is true and no queue is bound that matches the routing key, or when the immediate flag is true and no consumer on the matched queue is ready to accept the delivery." As per my understanding, that means if you set `mandatory` to false, you will get no notification  in case the server rejects a message and/or encounters any other problem during delivery. Try with mandatory set to true.

Comment: This will only work properly though if you add a [listener on NotifyReturn](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.NotifyReturn). And maybe even with immediate set to true.